# Show variable names in interaction plot

Tags: r

I have a couple of predictor variables (v1,v2,v3) and want to check for interactions between them on an outcome variable (outcome) using interaction.plot().

The idea is to do this in an automated way (I have way more than 3 variables in my "real dataset).

```
   v1<-c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0))
   v2<-c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0)
   v3<-c(4,5,2,5,7,3,5,3,2,1)
   outcome<-c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0)
   df<-data.frame(v1,v2,v3,outcome)
   a<-c("v1" , "v2" , "v3")
   b<-c("v1" , "v2" , "v3")

   par("mar")
   par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
   par(mfrow=c(3,3))
   for (i in 1:3){
     for (j in 1:3){
       interaction.plot(df[,a[i]], df[,b[j]], df$outcome)
     }  
   }
```

The plot looks like this:
[image: Interaction Plot Matrix]

Now I would like to put the variable names into the charts by inserting lab and ylab like this:

```
interaction.plot(df[,a[i]], df[,b[j]], df$outcome, xlab=colnames(df)[i], ylab=colnames(df)[j])
```

When I run this, nothing happens (the chart looks like before).

Any tips?

-p

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing seems to happen is you have the margins set too small so the axis labels don't have room to appear. You can get them to appear again by allowing more space on the bottom and left:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,1,1))
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for (i in 1:3){
    for (j in 1:3){
        interaction.plot(df[,a[i]], df[,b[j]], df$outcome, 
                         xlab=colnames(df)[i], ylab=colnames(df)[j])
    }  
}
```

To keep the axis labels while tightening the margins a bit, you can also use the `mgp` parameter to play with the spacing between the plot region and the axis labels, although finding the right balance seems to be hard to achieve:

```
par(mar=c(3,3,1,1), mgp = c(1, 0, 0))
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for (i in 1:3){
    for (j in 1:3){
        interaction.plot(df[,a[i]], df[,b[j]], df$outcome, 
                         xlab=colnames(df)[i], ylab=colnames(df)[j])
    }  
}
```